# ssh to Cisco device not working

Tags: ssh, openssh

I have an issue where my server is not able to ssh to a cisco device after upgrading the server to the latest version.

I did a `ssh -vvv,` I am not sure about two sections. Below are the details :

I want to know the meaning of ciphers ctos and ciphers stoc

**ciphers ctos**: `chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com`

**ciphers stoc**: `chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com`

Also at the end of the log, got info : 
Unable to negotiate with 10.44.39.202 port 22: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: `diffie-hellman-group1-sha1`

Is it okay to add `diffie-hellman-group1-sha1` to the host key algorithms?

The below is the debug log :

```
-bash-4.0# ssh -vvv 10.44.39.202 OpenSSH_7.7p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2j-fips  26 Sep 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /usr/etc/ssh_config
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 10.44.39.202 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 10.44.39.202 [10.44.39.202] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version Cisco-1.25
debug1: match: Cisco-1.25 pat Cisco-1.* compat 0x60000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 10.44.39.202:22 as 'root'
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5,hmac-md5-96
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5,hmac-md5-96
debug2: compression ctos: none
debug2: compression stoc: none
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: (no match)

Unable to negotiate with 10.44.39.202 port 22: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

Comment: Would you please add distro?

Comment: distro : centos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your upgraded OpenSSH no longer includes diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 as a key exchange algorithm by default, yet that's the only key exchange algorithm that the Cisco device is offering.

The quickest work-around would be to tell your SSH client that it's OK to use diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 in communication with that device. Add a stanza to your ~/.ssh/config like this:

```
Host 10.44.39.202
  KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

Reference:

[OpenSSH legacy options](https://www.openssh.com/legacy.html):

> If the client and server are unable to agree on a mutual set of parameters then the connection will fail. OpenSSH (7.0 and greater) will produce an error message like this:
>
> ```
>    Unable to negotiate with legacyhost: no matching key exchange method found.
>    Their offer: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
> ```

Comment: Thanks Jeff!

I added the kex algorithm to the .ssh file, after which I got a no matching cipher found, I added the ciphers offered by the server to the .ssh file, got the connection established. 

Cheers! :)